# Why I Couldn't make fullscreen in wxpython(Not Working ShowFullscreen in dialog)

Tags: python, dialog, wxpython, fullscreen, showmodaldialog

I found "ShowFullscreen" to make full screen. First Frame(MyFrame) is Fullscreen. But I coun't make fullscreen other dialog(emerg_Dialog and call_Dialog) 
I don't want to see any title or toolbar in dialog.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx
import wx.media


class emerg_Dialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1280,800))

        if self.IsFullScreen():
            self.ShowFullScreen(False)
        else:
            self.ShowFullScreen(True)

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,0,0))


class call_Dialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1280,800))

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):                
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1280,800))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(7,56,99))

        button_1 = wx.Button(self, label="emerg", pos=(100,550), size=(300,150))
        button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnEmerg)



        button_cancel = wx.Button(self, label="destory", pos=(490,550), size=(300,150))
        button_cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseWindow)

        button_2 = wx.Button(self, label="call", pos=(490,550), size=(300,150))
        button_2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCall)


    def OnEmerg(self, event):
        emerg = emerg_Dialog(self, -1, '')
        #self.ShowFullScreen(self.IsFullScreen(), wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)
      #  self.emerg.ShowFullScreen(True)
      #  self.emerg.SetTopWindow(self.main)

        emerg_1 = emerg.ShowModal()

        emerg.Destroy()

    def OnCall(self, event):
        call = call_Dialog(self, -1, '')
        call1 = call.ShowModal()
        call1.Destroy()


    def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

#    def OnFullScreen(self,event):
#        self.ShowFullScreen(not self.IsFullScreen(), wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)

class TestApp(wx.App):                  ##
    def OnInit(self):
        self.main = MyFrame(None,-1,'')
        self.main.Show()
        self.main.ShowFullScreen(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.main)
        return True

def main():
    application = TestApp(redirect=False)
    application.MainLoop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I couldn't find out why. but I found a alternative. using wx.Frame(multi Frame in wxpython)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but. It works in wx.Frame form

```
import wx
import wx.media


class emerg_Dialog(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1280,800))


        self.ShowFullScreen(True)

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,0,0))


class call_Dialog(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1280,800))

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):                
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1280,800))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(7,56,99))

        button_1 = wx.Button(self, label="emerg", pos=(100,550), size=(300,150))
        button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnEmerg)



        button_cancel = wx.Button(self, label="destory", pos=(490,550), size=(300,150))
        button_cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCloseWindow)

        button_2 = wx.Button(self, label="call", pos=(490,550), size=(300,150))
        button_2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCall)


    def OnEmerg(self, event):
        emerg = emerg_Dialog(self, -1, '')
        #self.ShowFullScreen(self.IsFullScreen(), wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)
      #  self.emerg.ShowFullScreen(True)
      #  self.emerg.SetTopWindow(self.main)

        emerg_1 = emerg.ShowModal()

        emerg.Destroy()

    def OnCall(self, event):
        call = call_Dialog(self, -1, '')
        call1 = call.ShowModal()
        call1.Destroy()


    def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

#    def OnFullScreen(self,event):
#        self.ShowFullScreen(not self.IsFullScreen(), wx.FULLSCREEN_ALL)

class TestApp(wx.App):                  ##
    def OnInit(self):
        self.main = MyFrame(None,-1,'')
        self.main.Show()
        self.main.ShowFullScreen(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.main)
        return True

def main():
    application = TestApp(redirect=False)
    application.MainLoop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```